# Pointer confusion

Tags: c++, pointers

I am fairly novice at C++, and I'm having an error that I just don't understand.

```
class1* a = (class1*)p1;
class2* b = (class2*)p2;
a->foo(b);
```

The error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'a::foo(b*&)'
note: candidates are: void a::foo(const b&)
```

How do I get this right?

Comment: It's obvious from the error message that the code you showed us is not the same code you tried to compile. In the future, show us your *actual* code, not a from-memory approximation.

Comment: @ildjam: I would actually think that the error message is quite related to the code presented: trying to call a method `foo` of the class `a` using as argument an lvalue of type `b*`, which matches `a->foo( b )` perfectly.

Comment: @dribeas: except that somewhere between the real code and this question, the type `a` has been renamed to `class1` and `b` to `class2`, then the variables named after the old type names.

Comment: This is copied directly, and variables renamed (because they're long, ugly, and distract from the point) - thanks to those who helped!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably have to do

```
  a->foo(*b);
```

because foo takes a reference to b not a pointer to b.

[What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c) is a good place to learn the difference between a pointer and a reference in C++

Comment: @Sticky: Do you understand the difference between references, pointers and address of objects?

Answer (score 4):

You're calling a function that expects a reference to an object with a pointer to said object (which is an incompatible type). To get the code to compile, you want to call foo like this:

```
a->foo(*b);
```

Essentially you're dereferencing the pointer to get the actual object and pass that one to `foo`. The compiler takes care of passing a reference to the object instead of the object itself.